# Hanging phone while creating thousands line listview in jQuerymobile

Tags: jquery, list, listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

we want to create thousands line listview in jQuerymobile using mobile phoneGap.

we are declaring 3000 line list **using < LI >** using jQuery in page, so my phone is taking lot of time for loading The page.
and same problem is occurring while searching data from listview.

**CODE:**

```
<div data-demo-html="true">
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search cars..." data-theme="a">
<li><a href="#">list_line_0001</a></li>
    ...                                              //3000+ lines are here 
<li><a href="#">list_line_3000</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

we dont want to use INTERNET.

sorry for my English/Grammer.

Comment: so what is your question? Of course "a phone" needs time to generate 3000 list items. If you do it in the browser, you are limited to what your browser can handle.

Comment: i am trying to load data using **autocomplete jQuery** but we need all data in listview, is it possible???

[i am using LINK](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: while my app will work on list of data, it is taking time to load all <li>. so, can we do easy way means faster load all <li> element

Comment: so there are 3 things... 1) time to load over network = you cannot do anything about it, 2) time to assemble on server = what are you sending JSON? HTML? and 3) time to render on client = you may be faster enhancing list elements with native JavaScript overriding JQM.

Comment: but in general, I think it's bad practice to upfront-load 3000 items. Can you not load 50 + pagination? If you do remote autocomplete, just load the first 50 and when the user searches for "foo", run a new query and return the matching records.l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this examples from jquery mobile site :

**Autocomplete :**
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/autocomplete/

**Remote autocomplete :**
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/autocomplete/autocomplete-remote.html

I faced this problem with JQM list view when there are many items , you can use somthing fast for mobile  to populate the listview like  :

**topcoat**
http://topcoat.io/

Or

**Bootstrap**
http://getbootstrap.com/